# CSS / jQuery Multilevel List

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a multilevel list which should initially look like the following:

```
    Level_1
    Level_1
```

then when I click on one of the "Level_1" text (say the top one), "Level_2" should appear, like so:

```
    Level_1
        Level_2
        Level_2
    Level_1
```

then when I click on "Level_2" (say the bottom one), "Level_3" should appear under the "Level_2" that has been clicked, like so:

```
    Level_1
        Level_2
        Level_2
            Level_3
            Level_3
            Level_3
    Level_1
```

then when I click on the second "Level_2" again, it should revert back to

```
    Level_1
        Level_2
        Level_2
    Level_1
```

The following is what I have so far (I'm suspecting that it doesn't work as the jQuery function activates twice when I click "Level_2", once for "Level_1" (as "Level_2" is embedded within "Level_1") and once for "Level_2"):

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".Level_3").click(function(){
    console.log( $(this) )
        jQuery(this).find(".Level_4").toggle();
    });

    $(".Level_2").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".Level_3").toggle();
    });

    $(".Level_1").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).find(".Level_2").toggle();
    });

});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.Level_1 {
    text-indent: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: Red;
}

.Level_2 {
    text-indent: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: Green;
}

.Level_3 {
    text-indent: 75px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: Blue;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="Level_1">
Level_1
    <div class="Level_2">
        Level_2
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Level_2">
        Level_2
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Level_1">
Level_1
    <div class="Level_2">
        Level_2
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="Level_2">
        Level_2
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
        <div class="Level_3">Level_3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How it should look like after each "Level_1" and "Level_2" has been clicked once ("Level_3" will later become a link to another page):

```
    Level_1
        Level_2
            Level_3
        Level_2
            Level_3
            Level_3
            Level_3
    Level_1
        Level_2
            Level_3
        Level_2
            Level_3
            Level_3
            Level_3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should control target of click event

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $(".Level_3").click(function(e){
      if ( $(e.target).is('.Level_3') ){
         $(this).find(".Level_4").toggle();
       }
    });

    $(".Level_2").click(function(e){
      if ( $(e.target).is('.level_2') ){
          $(this).find(".Level_3").toggle();
       }
    });

    $(".Level_1").click(function(e){
        if ( $(e.target).is('.level_1') ){
           $(this).find(".Level_2").toggle();
        }
    });

});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/kakajewi/1/)

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to maintain a div-style layout I would recommend doing something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MDp5h/5/**

It only requires a minor bit of a markup change in the html and a few lines of css (see below). It also provides a couple benefits-

1. All menus will start closed
2. The jQuery is short and clean
3. The jQuery will work no matter the number of dropdown levels as long as they follow the same HTML layout pattern and doesn't require that they have unique ID's or classes

**If you'd like to see how to do it with lists instead of divs check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/MDp5h/4/**

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="Level_1">
        <a href="#">Level_1</a>
        <div class="Level_2"> 
            <a href="#">Level_2</a>
            <div class="Level_3">
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Level_2">
            <a href="#">Level_2</a>
            <div class="Level_3">
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Level_1">
        <a href="#">Level_1</a>
        <div class="Level_2">
            <a href="#">Level_2</a>
            <div class="Level_3">
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Level_2">
            <a href="#">Level_2</a>
            <div class="Level_3">
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
                <a href="#">Level_3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav div div {
    display:none;
}
#nav a{
    display: block;
}
.Level_1 {
    text-indent: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: Red;
}
.Level_2 {
    text-indent: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: Green;
}
.Level_3 {
    text-indent: 75px;
    z-index: 3;
    background-color: Blue;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nav div a').click(function() {
    if($(this).parent('div').children('div').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).parent('div').children('div').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $(this).parent('div').children('div').css('display', 'none');
    };
});
```

Comment: The code you have provided (for jQuery) looks a bit complicated for me to add additional animation effects. (I'm only a beginner with jQuery!)

Comment: It's actually super simple. Instead of changing the css on this line:  
`$(this).parent('div').children('div')**.css('display', 'block')**;`  


You instead just add an animation (such as slide) like this:  
`$(this).parent('div').children('div')**.slideDown()**;`  


You can see an example of that here: http://jsfiddle.net/MDp5h/6/